# When using a car to generate electricity, what factors affect its efficiency?

Tags: electrical, efficiency, inverter

A group of friends and I are all going camping, and have some minor back-up power needs (and no generator).  We're trying to figure out which of our cars is best to plug an inverter into: most efficient as a generator.

Some of the factors I imagine go into this:

1. **Is it a hybrid?**  I suspect that hybrids are generally better at turning fuel into electricity.
2. **Gas mileage per weight:** a pseudo measure of fuel efficiency at idle
3. **Newer/Older:** it's probably safe to assume that newer cars expect to be used as a source of electricity more often due to the screens, sound system, and charging ports all being in frequent use.
4. **What else?** I don't expect this to be an exact science (though it would be nice).  Just some general idea of who's car to plug into.

Comment: In general, a vehicle with the smallest engine tends to have the best fuel mileage but all engines in regular driving use have between 20%-35% thermal efficiency. The other 65%-80% is lost as heat; mechanical friction, cooling  system drawing heat away from cylinder walls, oil absorbing combustion heat and exhaust.  All waste energy. As long as someone has jumper cables, if a battery is depleted from starting, a boost from another vehicle will prevent that one vehicle from being stranded.

Comment: Do you think they have the best fuel mileage because the engine is better, or because the car is smaller?  It seems like -- at idle -- the lost multiplier of weight/inertia would change the product a lot.

Comment: Would just pick the smaller engine. You cant even be sure if you look at specs online, because different mechanical situations can make it run off spec. To be absolutely sure you have to run all vehicles from full gas at idle till empty and calculate, which is rather silly. Just pick a vehicle and everyone split the gas money on that vehicle

Comment: There are two separate issues; one is inverter power consumption drawing 12v battery power for small things like a laptop, cellphone charger, etc for less than an hour without requiring the engine then using the engine's alternator while idling to supply all the power an inverter can use for longer periods without discharging the battery. Presuming no one uses an electric chain saw, ac heater or hair dryer, all drawing a lot of current, most inverters will work fine. The engine's efficiency remains the same regardless of vehicle weight. Smallest cars,smallest engines = less fuel driving.

Comment: Okay, small car makes sense.  What about hybrid engines?  Aren't those specifically designed for fuel -> electrical efficiency?

Comment: Are you planning on running the vehicle while the inverter is plugged in, or is this for when things are stationary and turned off?

Comment: Yes, but, the smaller car will have a smaller battery.

Comment: Unless the hybrid vehicle uses the hybrid side of the battery to power an inverter, the 12v battery in a hybrid (presumed 12v battery is used for engine starting) operates the same as a regular ice vehicle. It needs to be recharged after every engine startup to top off the battery like all vehicles with ice technology. If the hybrid has a 12v battery for engine starting, it may be smaller than most vehicle batteries so you'd have to take that into consideration of using a hybrid vehicle to power the inverter with possibly less capacity compared to most car batteries (engine off scenario).